# Can't Overload Operator '+' for object class

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, operator-overloading

I have two or more variables of class `object` in c# which has integer values. i want to overload '+' operator so that i won't have to convert these variables when ever i want to add or subtract them. here is my code below:

```
public static object operator +( object obj1, object obj2)
{
    object o = Convert.toint32(obj1) + Convert.toint32(obj2);
   return o;
}
```

no the problem is i am getting an error saying **`"One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type"`**

why is this happening? any help is appreciated!

Comment: wow 5 answers in 40 seconds - is that an SO record?

Comment: Move the Overload Operator to the same class as one of the parameters. In your case, the entire Overload needs to be in the object class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler error tells you *exactly* what's wrong - if you're going to create a custom binary operator, at least one of the parameter types (for the operands) has to be the same as the type you're declaring the operator in (or a nullable version of it, for value types).

This is mandated in section 10.10.2  of the [C# 4 specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc):

> The following rules apply to binary operator declarations, where T denotes the instance type of the class or struct that contains the operator declaration:
>
> - A binary non-shift operator must take two parameters, at least one of which must have type T or T?, and can return any type.
> - A binary `<<` or `>>` operator must take two parameters, the first of which must have type T or T? and the second of which must have type int or int?, and can return any type.

Personally I would try to avoid having variables of type `object` if you know they're actually `int` values. Why not have `int` variables instead?

If you're using C# 4, another alternative would be to make them `dynamic` variables, where the operator overloading would be applied at execution time rather than compile time.

Comment: actually i saw a question on here about adding multiple objects of type Object, so i was thinking if i could override '+' operator but i didnt know its not possible, anyways Thanks you were informative!

Answer (score 4):

You can't override the operator for existing classes: only your own classes.

Comment: You can't *override* operators at all - you can only *overload* them.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that, of course. Just checking everyone was awake ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This seems **silly/ridiculous**, the objects are `int`s, and because you don't want to cast, you'll make your code less readable by adding `object`s (which seems crazy)?  What happens when you want to do `myObj + 1`?  You'll need to make a massive array of operators and overloads and it's not worth the effort.

Use the correct type in the first place, for the sake of whoever has to read or maintain the code in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that you want to add two objects of type `object`, you can't do that.

As the error message says, one of the two parameters to the operator method has to be the type where you defined the operator.

ie. if you declared the operator inside a class with the name XYZ, either `obj1` or `obj2` has to be of that type.

You cannot declare operator overloads for unrelated types.

Basically, you can't do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is telling you exactly the problem.

You can't 'inject' an operator overload into somebody else's types - an operator overload must apply to the type in which you declare it.

The term 'apply' in this case is then explained by the compiler error: one of the parameters must be of that type; the other parameter can be of any type.

So, for example:

```
public class MyType
{
  public static object operator +(MyType obj1, object obj2){
    //define code for adding the object to 'MyType' and return object,
    //or whatever type you want.
  }
}
```

In this example we are creating an operator between `MyType` and `object` and it works because it's defined inside `MyType`.  All binary operator overloads must follow the same rule.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the operator in a class, let's say `class Foo`. The compiler tells you that at least one of the two operands must have a static type of `Foo`, for example:

```
public static object operator +( Foo obj1, object obj2)
{
    object o = Convert.toint32(obj1) + Convert.toint32(obj2);
    return o;
}
```

It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here. If you have objects of `class Foo` but their static type is `object`, then you can't do anything such unless you cast them to `Foo` first.